# How to implement actionListener

Tags: swing, actionlistener

I was developing a `Java Swing` application to `select data` from the `database`.But my `Action Listener` doesn't work. Please help me. No errors are showing while executing the program.Please check my code.

```
public class Availability implements ActionListener {

    JPanel panelForMedicine,inputPanel;
    JLabel mediLabel;
    JComboBox listCombo;
    JButton dbButton;
    final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/paliative_care_unit";
    final String USER = "root";
    final String PASS = "root";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt=null;

    static void guiBuilder(){
        JFrame availabilityFrame=new JFrame("Check Stock");
        availabilityFrame.setLocation(0, 0);
        availabilityFrame.setSize(390,150);
        availabilityFrame.setVisible(true);
        availabilityFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(availabilityFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        Availability availability=new Availability();
        availabilityFrame.setContentPane(availability.mainPanel());
        availability.mainPanel();
    }

    public JPanel mainPanel(){
        JPanel availabilityPanel=new JPanel();
        availabilityPanel.setLayout(null);

        panelForMedicine=new JPanel();
        //panelForMedicine.setLayout(null);
        panelForMedicine.setSize(70, 40);
        panelForMedicine.setLocation(30, 35);

        availabilityPanel.add(panelForMedicine);

        mediLabel=new JLabel("Medicine");
        mediLabel.setLocation(0, 0);
        mediLabel.setSize(70, 40);
        panelForMedicine.add(mediLabel);

        inputPanel=new JPanel();
        inputPanel.setLayout(null);
        inputPanel.setSize(150, 40);
        inputPanel.setLocation(120,35);
        availabilityPanel.add(inputPanel);

        listCombo=new JComboBox();
        listCombo.setSize(150, 30);
        listCombo.setLocation(0, 0);
        inputPanel.add(listCombo);

        try{
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql="SELECT  DISTINCT medi FROM paliative"; 

            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while(rs.next()){
                listCombo.addItem(rs.getString("medi"));
                //medicineField.setSelectedItem("attempt11");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}

        dbButton=new JButton("GO");
        dbButton.setSize(70, 30);
        dbButton.setLocation(300, 35);
        dbButton.addActionListener(this);

        availabilityPanel.add(dbButton);
        availabilityPanel.setOpaque(true);
        return availabilityPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource()==dbButton){
            System.out.println("Checking");
            try{
                System.out.println("Checking");
                Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                String sql="SELECT  * FROM paliative WHERE medi='"+listCombo.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'";
                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                while(rs.next()){
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                JFrame dialogFrame=new JFrame();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialogFrame, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking your sql query ? :)

Comment: Why are you calling `availability.mainPanel()` twice in your `guiBuilder()` method ? Moreover, `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` is a static field, please do learn about conventions, this field must be referenced with the `Class Name` not the reference of it. Such things make it a bit confusing while understanding the concept you are using and why the situation as described by you occurred.

Comment: If you go to the hospital and tell the doctor «It doesn't work», he will answer you with questions. So here I am, what exactly doesn't work ? :-)

Comment: While clicking the dbButton nothing happens

Comment: just fyi, you have a SQL injection vulnerability right here: ```String sql="SELECT  * FROM paliative WHERE medi='"+listCombo.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'"```

Comment: That's ok but the print statement before that also not working

Comment: Does it print "Checking" in the console ? What if you print something before the condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @nicE cOw points out - you are calling `availability.mainPanel()` twice in your `guiBuilder()` method.  This will change your reference to the `dbButton` variable after it was added to your contentPane, which will make the `if(e.getSource()==dbButton)` condition fail in your action listener

Solution: remove the second call to `availability.mainPanel();` in `guiBuilder()`

Also:
Please read up on Swing threading.  You should not be doing long running actions (like database calls) in the Event Dispatch Thread.  Try [Concurrency In Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for starters.

Comment: @bhavisankar : Please have a look at [how accepting an answer works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/204608), since if you think this answer did helped you, please mark it as an answer, to help future visitors :-)